# How to model a MongoDB database to efficiently display set of values of a given array field

Tags: mongodb

Let's pretend we want to design a MongoDB database for an app that stores data about books.

Each book can have many tags:

```
Book = {
    title,       // String
    description, // String
    tags: []     // Array of String
}
```

I want a page in which I can list all the tags (possibly tens of thousands of tags) and have it paginated.

It is inefficient to run a query to aggregate the set of all tags for all books and eliminate the duplicates whenever the user wants to view this page.

How can I design my database to make the aforementioned scenario efficient and responsive?

*P.S: Ideally I don't like to have a Topic collection to solve this problem.*

Comment: can you give some more detail?

Answer (score 2):

The following query will give you all distinct tags sorted:

```
db.books.distinct("tags", {}).sort({tags : 1});
```

However, to make it efficient you need to index the tags field. This way, the index will be used to fetch and sort the results.

```
db.books.ensureIndex({tags: 1});
```

As you can see in the docs (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) the distinct operation will use an index if available, and if it is covered like your case, even better.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the one of solutions could look like this:

```
Book = {
    title,       // String
    description, // String
    tags: []     // Array of String (Tag names)
}

Tag = {
    name         // String
}
```

`name` of Tag should be unique, so if user add new book and add some tag to it, you could find this tag in Tags collection, and if this tag exists you add `name` of it to `tags` array in Book document, and in case when this tag is not exist you add it to Tags collection and `name` of it to `tags` array in Book document. And when user click to some tag to view all related books, you should find all books with this tag in `tags` array. Also, you could use `_id` field as tag name and use String instead of ObjectId.

Another solution:

```
Book = {
    title,       // String
    description  // String
}

Tag = {
    name,        // String
    books: []    // Array of books titles or ids
}
```

In this case, when user add some book and tag, you should find this tag in Tags collection, create it if it's not exist, and than add book `_id` to `books` array in this Tag document. And when user click to some tag to view all related books, you could find all books using `books` array in Tag document.

Comment: By saying he/she doesn't want a Topic collection I believe he/she meant not having a different referencing collection to store tags like you are proposing.